# C#, winform - Spinning Wheel progress breaks and resumes intermittently

Tags: c#, activity-indicator

Showing a Spin wheel progress animated gif while user initiates a long running process.
When i click the start, the process starts and same time wheel starts rotating.

But the problem is, the wheel strucks in-between and resumes, that happen multiple times during the long run process.  It should be continuously rotation.  I am running both the task and animated gif in same thread (**since the indicator is just an animated image not a real progress value**).

Code used is,

```
        this.progressPictureBox.Visible = true;
        this.Refresh(); // this - an user controll
        this.progressPictureBox.Refresh();
        Application.DoEvents();
        OnStartCalibration(); // Starts long running process
        this.progressPictureBox.Visible = false;
```

---

```
   OnStartCalibration()
   {      

        int count = 6;  
        int sleepInterval = 5000;
        bool success = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            m_keywordList.Clear();
            m_keywordList.Add("HeatCoolModeStatus");
            m_role.ReadValueForKeys(m_keywordList, null, null);
            l_currentValue = (int)m_role.GetValue("HeatCoolModeStatus");
            if (l_currentValue == 16)
            {
                success = true;
                break;
            }    
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleepInterval);
        }
}
```

How do I show uninterrupted continuous display of wheel till the process ends?

Comment: Please post some code on how are you handling the long running process.. BackgroundWorker? BeginInvoke?

Answer (score 1):

If you use framework 4, replace the `OnStartCalibration(); // Starts long running process` line with the following code:

```
BackgroundWorker bgwLoading = new BackgroundWorker();
bgwLoading.DoWork += (sndr, evnt) =>
{
    int count = 6;  
    int sleepInterval = 5000;
    bool success = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        m_keywordList.Clear();
        m_keywordList.Add("HeatCoolModeStatus");
        m_role.ReadValueForKeys(m_keywordList, null, null);
        l_currentValue = (int)m_role.GetValue("HeatCoolModeStatus");
        if (l_currentValue == 16)
        {
            success = true;
            break;
        }    
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleepInterval);
    }
};
bgwLoading.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the progress indication and the task on the same thread. You should use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Your GUI thread will subscribe to the ProgressChanged event, and will be notified of updates to the task. From here, you can update the progress indication appropriately. There's also events for when the task is finished.